# python - writing into excel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl, xlwt

I m new to python. actually  I m able to parse an xml but don't know how to write this into excel.

sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
```

my Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
xmld = etree.parse('simple.xml')
root = xmld.getroot()
for child in root:
    for children in child:
     print children.tag," : % s" %children.text
```

output:

```
name  : Belgian Waffles
price  : $5.95
description  : Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup
calories  : 650
name  : Strawberry Belgian Waffles
price  : $7.95
description  : Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream
calories  : 900
```

Need to write this into excel like

'tags' into Column A and 'values' into column B
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5VK9.jpg)

Tried with xlwt or openpyxl or pandas..but no luck...pls help..

Comment: Try to make a dictionary from your output, then make a dataframe from that and write it into an excel file.

Comment: Is this issue actual yet or you got the answer?

Comment: Hi Vlad...yep tried with openpyxl like:

"     for row in zip({children.tag},{children.text}):
        ws.append(row)
        wb.save("simple.xls")  "

Now i can get the output as i expected. Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1):

From this site :  http://www.python-excel.org/ , you can try :

- openpyxl : https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/
- xlsxwriter : https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/
- xlrd : http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- xlwt : http://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- xlutils : http://xlutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Vlad..
i have improved my code as per below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
from openpyxl import Workbook
xmld = etree.parse('simple.xml')
root = xmld.getroot()
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
for child in root:
    for children in child:
     #print children.tag," : % s" %children.text
     for row in zip({children.tag},{children.text}):
        ws.append(row)
        wb.save("simple.xls")
```

Now i m successfully write into excel columns as expected.